# Facing issue on unity3d cmd line - executeMethod class could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a Unity Project targeting Android platform from the cmd line. The C# script to build the project with the required options is titled **PerformBuild.cs** and is inside the project path. The class contains the  method **ConfigureBuildTestApp** implemented.

```
$UNITY_PATH/Unity -quit -batchmmode -projectPath "$PROJECT_FINAL_PATH" -logFile -executeMethod PerformBuild.ConfigureBuildTestApp -buildTarget Android
```

The following error is observed in the build trace

```
executeMethod class 'PerformBuild' could not be found.
```

Argument was -executeMethod PerformBuild.ConfigureBuildTestApp

Any solution and/or reasoning for this problem? I followed the forum posts in the [unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/executemethod-class-performbuild-could-not-be-found.222644/) but none was helpful.

**The script PerformBuild.cs**

[image: PerformBuild.cs]

Compilation Errors were observed with the script above. Fixed the compilation errors and the revised script is shown below.

**Revised PerformBuild.cs**
[image: Script for building Android APK]
The initial error for -executeMethod is still observed.

```
executeMethod class 'PerformBuild' could not be found.

Argument was -executeMethod 
testIntegrationProject.PerformBuild.ConfigureBuildTestApp

(Filename: 
/Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Utilities/Argv.cpp 
Line: 295)
```

Comment: What does the performbuild.cs look like?

Comment: @FredrikWiderberg, I attached it to the post. Thanks

Comment: Strange. Does it help if you add the full namespace to the commandline? like `-executeMethod GenerateUnityApp.PerformBuild.ConfigureBuildTestApp`

Comment: Tried that already. It was mentioned in the unity forum link i included.

Comment: Is it located in Assets/Editor/?

Comment: When you echo `$PROJECT_FINAL_PATH` what does it return? Have you tried hard-coding the value? Maybe its a permissions thing.

Comment: @Hristo I set that variable. It points to the project root folder. It returns something similar to:
/Users/[user-name]/[project-title]/

Comment: Try to hard-code it with the exact project path

Comment: @FredrikWiderberg it is.

Answer (score 1):

We had the "executeMethod class could not be found" error when a new plugin was used but was not present in the remote build server, causing all C# code to not compile, hence the error. Try manually building the project on the machine where you are building via command line and see if it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the namespace from class PerformBuild